Type safe select list in React without type casting?
I'm using a select element in React with TypeScript.
const allArtists = ["elvis", "dr dre"] as const;
type Artist = (typeof allArtists)[number];

function App() {
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState<Artist | "">("");

  function handleArtistChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    const newArtist = e.target.value as Artist | "";
    setArtist(newArtist);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={artist} onChange={handleArtistChange}>
        <option value={""}>Please choose</option>
        {allArtists.map((a) => (
          <option key={a} value={a}>
            {a}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

The code above isn't great as if an illegal value is added as an option I don't get TypeScript errors:
<option value={"ILLEGAL VALUE"}>Please choose</option>

I know one option would be to check if the string passed to handleArtistChange appears in allArtists. This also isn't ideal as there is a runtime performance, and "ILLEGAL VALUE" still doesn't produce a compile time error.
Is there a compile time solution that doesn't use type casting?

Not without extracting something, but surely it's easy enough to have e.g. <TypedSelect<Artist> value={artist} onChange={handleArtistChange} options={...} />.

With some contortions and a couple helper components, at least:
import * as React from "react";

const allArtists = ["elvis", "dr dre"] as const;
type Artist = typeof allArtists[number];

interface TypedSelectChangeEvent<ValueT extends string> extends React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement> {
  target: EventTarget & (Omit<HTMLSelectElement, "value"> & { value: ValueT | "" });
}

function TypedOption<T extends string>(
  props: Omit<React.OptionHTMLAttributes<HTMLOptionElement>, "value"> & { value?: T | "" },
) {
  return <option {...props} />;
}
function TypedSelect<T extends string>(
  props: Omit<React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, "value" | "onChange"> & {
    value?: T | "";
    onChange?: React.EventHandler<TypedSelectChangeEvent<T>>;
  },
) {
  return <select {...props} />;
}

function App() {
  const [artist, setArtist] = React.useState<Artist | "">("");

  function handleArtistChange(e: TypedSelectChangeEvent<Artist>) {
    setArtist(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <TypedSelect value={artist} onChange={handleArtistChange}>
        <TypedOption<Artist> value="">Please choose</TypedOption>
        {allArtists.map((a) => (
          <TypedOption<Artist> key={a} value={a}>
            {a}
          </TypedOption>
        ))}
      </TypedSelect>
    </div>
  );
}


The simplest, if you don't want to fight with module augmentations and so, is to create a custom component. I would go with a very simple approach using render props:
type TypesafeSelectProps<T> = {
  options?: T[];
  children: (iterationElement: T) => JSX.Element;
};

const TypesafeSelect = <T,>({ options, children }: TypesafeSelectProps<T>) => (
  <select>{options?.map((opt) => children(opt))}</select>
);

This approach allows the user to set either the option component he wants and also the set of props, without adding any level of complexity. The user also gets type inference in the argument of the render props as well as type safety:
const listOfComplexObj = [
  { name: "Michael", age: 12 },
  { name: "John", age: 22 },
  { name: "Eva", age: 40 },
];

Usage:
<TypesafeSelect options={listOfComplexObj}>
  {({ age, name }) => (
    <option key={age} value={age}>
      {name}
    </option>
  )}
</TypesafeSelect>

If that works for you, just extend the base interface with SelectProps to properly set the props for the select element. You could even override the type for the value, but potentially you would like this to not be typed, or at least to have a type other than T:
interface TypesafeSelectProps<T>
  extends Omit<
    React.DetailedHTMLProps<
      React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>,
      HTMLSelectElement
    >,
    "children"
  > {
  options: T[];
  children: (iterationElement: T) => JSX.Element;
}

const TypesafeSelect = <T,>({
  options,
  children,
  ...selectProps
}: TypesafeSelectProps<T>) => (
  <select {...selectProps}>{options?.map((opt) => children(opt))}</select>
);

